# How to setup WIndows 2008 as a NFS server for clonezilla

Tags: windows-server-2008, nfs, clonezilla

This sounded like an easy task to me, use clonezilla to image a laptop to a windows 2008 R2 NFS server.

I got the clonezilla Live CD to boot on the Laptop.  I got into the command line. I was able to ping the Win2008 box; but I can't mount the windows NFS drive.

I added the NFS role to windows 2008 made a folder called "home" and gave it "Allow Anonymous access" and file permissions ALL Machines ANSI Read-Write Root Access Allowed.
I also turned off the windows firewall.

From the clonezilla command line I typed
sudo mount 10.0.0.143:/home /home/partimag
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting (null)

I don't use linux much so it hard for me to debug this problem; any help welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I got it working with an SSH/SFTP program called core FTP server.
Would still like to know why NFS didn't work.